# Tangent to the curve $y=x^2-6x+14$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find value of constant $k$ for which the line $y+2x=k$ is a tangent to the curve $y=x^2-6x+14$.
I am very confused. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=x^2-6x+14$$
$$y'=2x-6$$

the slope of line $y=-2x+k$ is -2
so
$$-2=2x-6$$
$$x=2$$

find the value of $y$ by plug the $x$ in curve equation
$$y=(2)^2-6(2)+14$$
$$y=6$$

now you can subsitute the pont $(2,6)$ in the line equation to get $k$

Answer (score 2):

You can solve simultaneously to find the points of intersection. You will end up with a quadratic equation in terms of k. For the line to be a tangent of the curve, the solutions of this quadratic equation (the intercepts) must be equal. Thus use b^2-4ac=0 to find the value of k.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=k-2x$$
The slope is $-2$

For the curve:
$$y=x^2-6x+14$$
The slope of the tangent is the derivative
$$y'=2x-6$$
We want them to be equal
$$2x-6=-2$$
$$x=2$$
Now all you have left is to find $k$ such that
$$(-2)^2-6(-2)+14=k-2(-2)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Geometrical Approach**

Notice, solve the given equations for intersection point.

Substituting the value of $y=k-2x$ into the equation $y=x^2-6x+14$, we get 
$$k-2x=x^2-6x+14$$ $$x^2-4x+14-k=0$$
The given line: $y+2x=k$ will be tangent to the curve: $y=x^2-6x+14$ if and only the line intersects the curve at a single point i.e. the above equation equation has equal real roots hence, we have discriminant $\Delta =B^2-4AC=0$ $$(-4)^2-4(1)(14-k)=0$$  $$16-56+4k=0$$$$\implies 4k=40$$
$$\color{red}{k=10}$$